# Yet another Excel VBA CDate overflow error

Tags: excel, vba, macos, date, overflow

I have two simple VBA subs. One works OK (WorksOK). One produces an overflow error (DoesntWork). The difference between them is that WorksOK invokes a MsgBox. Both compute the date January 2, 2021 by adding one to CDate("January 1, 2021"). Can someone please explain why WorksOK works OK and DoesntWork doesn't work?

I observe this behavior **only** in:

- Excel **Mac** Catalina 16.44 VBA 7.1
- Word **Mac** Catalina 16.44 VBA 7.1.

Excel VBA in Windows seems to be OK.

```
Sub WorksOK()
    Dim j As Integer, y As Date
    j = 1
    y = CDate("January 1, 2021") + j
    Debug.Print y
    MsgBox y
    Debug.Print CDate("January 1, 2021") + j
End Sub

Sub DoesntWork()
    Dim j As Integer, y As Date
    j = 1
    y = CDate("January 1, 2021") + j
    Debug.Print y
    Debug.Print CDate("January 1, 2021") + j  'Overflow
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens with `Dim j As Long`?

Comment: The date of 1/1/2021 converts to a number of 44,197.  `Integer` maxes out at 32,767, therefore you receive an overflow error.

Comment: The behavior is the same wether j is Long or Integer

Comment: Darrell H: OK, suppose the size of date is the problem. Then why does VBA not complain in the Windows version? And why does the MsgBox matter?

Comment: Yeah, it seems Excel on Windows converts in the right way. Code runs on my WIndows computer.

Comment: @Vityata: If you refer to my comment: Yes, that works on my Windows computer as well.

Comment: @R.Brenner - Can you try with -j instead of +j?

Comment: What line returns the error?  What is your windows language setting?  In the immediate window, what is the result of `?isdate("January 1, 2021")`? and also `?CDate("January 1, 2021")`

Comment: @Viyata: Good idea,but the behavior is unchanged, for both WorksOK and DoesntWork, on Mac. I didn't check Windows, because things seem to be working there, and W is a little inconvenient for me. Maybe someone can check W.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld: The line that throws the error is the last line of the Sub DoesntWork. Since I'm on a Mac/Catalina, I don't have a Windows Language Setting. The Language and Region setting on my Mac (for me) is English U.S. ?isdate("January 1, 2021") returns True. ?CDate("January 1, 2021") returns 1/1/21

Comment: Thanks for that.  Unfortunately, that exhausts my thoughts. Sorry. I sure don't understand why it doesn't work on those versions, and I don't have anything here to test it with. For others who have reported problems with CDate on a Mac, it has usually been traced to a Mac Language and Region setting.

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell, but always handle dates as *dates*, not strings, not numbers, no exceptions.

This runs:

```vb
Sub DoesntWork()
    Dim j As Integer, y As Date
    j = 1
    y = DateAdd("d", j, #1/1/2021#)
    Debug.Print y
    Debug.Print DateAdd("d", j, #1/1/2021#)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmmm. Have you checked it on a Mac? When I did, I got the same behavior (ovflo on the last statement)

Comment: No, I have no Mac, but something else is going on; there is no way adding one day to a date prior to 9999-12-31 can cause an overflow. You can even `Dim j As Byte` and it will still work.

Comment: Yeah, it's a puzzle. If you think of experiments to run, let me know and I'll give them a go on a Mac.